# calculate months between two dates in hive

Tags: date, hive, hiveql

I am trying to find difference in months between currentdate and column (emp_joined) is lesser than 24 months.
The data type of column emp_joined is int. For this, I have written the below query to fetch the records.

select id,emp_joined from table where
(abs(month_between(cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yy-MM-dd'),from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(emp_joined as string),'yyMMdd'),'yy-MM-dd')as int)))<24)

But the query is returning all the records which are not lesser than 24 months between the currentdate and column emp_joined.
Can anyone help me with the query.

[image]

Comment: Where is the Unix timestamp data in the table? EMP_JOINED does not appear to be a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

months_between accepts dates in yyyy-MM-dd format. Try this

```
where abs(cast(months_between(current_date, 
                              from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(emp_joined as string),'yyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
              )as int)) < 24
```

Comment: I tried the above query it is not working. The issue is for records with id 1,2,3 the emp_joined is 2002  year's data. But when i convert it from unix_timestamp hive is considering it as 2022 year.

Comment: @AnushaRadhakrishnan it is because data is not in the yyMMdd format. I guess it is single digit month instead of two, right?

Comment: the month is in two digit.

Comment: @AnushaRadhakrishnan then 20331 means what ? Yr =2020 Mth=33 ??? day =1 How month can be 33

Comment: @AnushaRadhakrishnan If 20331 should be parsed as 2020-03-31, you can apply this logic for converting date: `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(emp_joined as string),case when length(cast(emp_joined as string))=5 then  'yyMdd' else 'yyMMdd' end),'yyyy-MM-dd')` Suppose it can be 5 or six digit number and if it is 5 digits then month is one digit. For 6 it is two digit month. You can add more conditions to the CASE according to your data